# How GBWhatsApp works?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, apk

I came across an application named GBWhatsApp. It is developed by some unknown people and there are many sites from where you can download the APK. It's not officially on the Play Store for some reason.

It was a big surprise to me to see that using this app, I can actually chat with the people who are using [the official WhatsApp application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp).

I did some googling and found out that it is a modded app of the original WhatsApp application. It is built on top of the original application. This means some people/developers/engineers decompiled the original APK and inserted their code and published it with another name.

My questions are,

- Is WhatsApp APK so much less secure that some engineers were able to decompile its Java code successfully? And they provided a lot of new features that are not there in the original app?
- I know APK can be decompiled, but if the original developer team has obfuscated the code (ProGuard, etc), then it's almost impossible to reverse engineer the Java code. How did this happen?
- Also, if it is not a modded app, it means they build their own app which is similar to WhatsApp, then how they are able to send messages to the official app?

Comment: nothing useful but maybe a little more information https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/whatsapp-gbwhatsapp-devices-t3518808

Comment: It's not a matter of "security" - any app can be decompiled, modified and reassembled. Moreover, obfuscation isn't a magic wand, as it's only a deterrent to rookie "hackers": if someone is persistent enough, they can eventually interpret what the different parts of a program actually do, edit them and get their own version to work. GBWhatsApp is an example.